# Linear Transformation from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$: image of $1$ dimensional subspace has dimension $1$ or $0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling to comprehend the question below. Especially the meaning of 'the image of $L$ under $F$'.
Let $F : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ be a linear transformation. Prove that if $L$ is a $1$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, then

$$F(L)=\{y \in \mathbb R^m \mid y=F(x),x \in L\}$$

the image of $L$ under $F$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^m$ with dimension $1$ or $0$. Hence prove that if the kernel of $F$ is $\{0\}$, the image of $L$ is a $1$- dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^m$ (and so in this case, $F$ takes lines in $\mathbb R^n$ to lines in $\mathbb R^m$).

Comment: Can you pinpoint the part of the definition that confuses you? The image of $L$ under $F$ is what is denoted $F(L)$.

Comment: The first thing that I'm unsure of is the Kernel of F a subspace of R^n?
Also im not sure how i can derive a vector from the above equation so that I can formulate an answer to the above linear transform

Comment: Im used to already being given a linear transform in the form of F(x,y,z)=(x,y+z), etc. Is there anyway I can turn the equation in the question into something representative of this form?

Comment: The is **very literally** the same question as was posted three days ago, except for :"I am struggling to comprehend" instead of "I am having trouble understanding". Curious!

Comment: Your problem with linear transformations is like you are used to salaries always being concrete amounts of money, and you cannot comprehend anybody discussing her salary without mentioning its exact amount. Those concrete linear transformations you rare used to should serve to get you used to the _general_ notion of linear transformation, which this question is about.